# No se puede asignar un argumento de tipo "string | ParsedQs | string[] | 10 | ParsedQs[]" al parámetro de tipo "number"

Tags: nodejs, typescript, mongodb, express

Estoy tratando de crear una funcion que me devuelva la lista de registros de una coleccion, debo recibir por parametros de request campos variables por los cuales debo ordenar, o establecer la paginacion, pero cuando intento hacerlo Typescript me muestra un error y quedo atascado alli, ya trate de implementar una interface pero igual me genera los mismos errores, muestro lo que me sucede:

```
   private getAllCondominios = ( request: Request, response: Response) => {
        const { perPage = 10, page = 0} = request.query
        const query = {estado: true}

        this.condominio
            .find( { $or: [ {estado: 1}, {estado: 2} ], ...query} )
            .limit(perPage) //<<=======Error aqui
            .skip(page) //<<=======Error aqui
            .then((condominios) => {
                response.send({condominios, total: condominios.length})
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                response.status(500)
                    .send({msg: `Error al intentar obtener el listado de condominion - Error: ${error}`})            
            });
    }
```

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'string | ParsedQs | string[] | 10 | ParsedQs[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

35             .limit(perPage)
```

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | ParsedQs | string[] | 0 | ParsedQs[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

36             .skip(page)
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Y si logras un condicional donde evalúes typeof page == 'number' ? Y si es true debería reconocer el type y si es false usas el default

Comment: Voy a probar, entonces, muchas gracias

Comment: Buscando en google consegui algo como esto:

`
        const page    : number = parseInt(request.query.page as any) || 0;
        const perPage : number = parseInt(request.query.perPage as any) || 10
`

y me libre del error

Comment: Evita usar `any`, mejor usar `unknown` o declarar explícitamente el tipo de dato recibido.